# Deleting files in the tree

Tags: bash, unix

Can you help me to find trouble with my code? It has to delete every files in the tree

```
function option_c {
for i in `find "$TEST_DIR" -type f | grep -E "(stdout|stderr|status)-(captured|delta)"` ; do
    if [ -w $i ] ; then
        rm $i
    fi
    exit 0
done
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the `exit`, it terminates your script after the first file.

You could do all of this with `find` itself, though.

Answer (score 1):

As tripleee mentions, you can do all in find:

```
find "$TEST_DIR" -type f -perm +0200 -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*st(dout|derr|atus)-(captured|delta).*" -delete
```

or

```
find "$TEST_DIR" -type f -perm +0200 -regex ".*st\(dout\|derr\|atus\)-\(captured\|delta\).*" -delete
```

```
find "$TEST_DIR" -type f -perm +0200 -exec egrep "(stdout|stderr|status)-(captured|delta)" {} ";" -delete
```

(at least gnu-find, which is all I have, has the -delete switch and the regex-options).

Comment: `-delete` doesn't appear to be [mandatory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/find.html) for the `find` command, but every version I've seen has it...

Comment: The `grep` in the original was for finding matching file names. I think you want `-rname 'st(dout|derr|atus)-(caputured|delta)'` but I'm not at my computer.

Comment: @tripleee: Yes, I guess you're right. Changed to -regex (gnu-find).